# AggregationBuilders throws an error JsonGenerationException

Tags: java, api, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch API (elasticsearch5.2.1.jar)to do the aggregation query as follows,

```
StatsAggregationBuilder statAggBuild = AggregationBuilders.stats("agg").field("ipAddress");
```

This returns the follows exception

```
{ "error" : "JsonGenerationException[Can not write a field name, expecting a value]"}
```

Am I doing anything wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not causing any issue while setting this Object in the request. It returns the response as expected

It looks the actual problem exist in the toString method, Which throws the error when we try to look what exist in the project